# TCP connection failure after kill+start docker image

Tags: python, linux, docker, networking, tcp

## **Background**

I have multiple python applications running in docker on the same machine. Each python application uses `twisted` to create server and client to communicate in `TCP`, ports that each process listens to are configured in a static file.

## **Problem**

SOMETIMES, only SOMETIMES, when I restart one or more docker images (I use `docker kill` and `docker run`), there is a chance a port that one application used before being killed is still being used.

After `docker run` command, `twisted` would throw `Unhandled error in Deferred:` error (without more details, only this line, maybe because of my logging configs), if and only if it is a problematic one.

Then I use `netstat -ntlp` to check that particular port, I find the port is not being listened. And I try `nc -l [PORT]`, it returns `Address already in use`. Also, I use `netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED` to find out some process(es) has/have already established a tcp connection to that port.

## **Means I tried to fix this problem temporarily**

1. I restarted the problematic docker image many times, until it listens to the port.
2. I killed other docker images that previously communicating with the problematic docker image, then restarted all killed images.

## **What is expected**

I would like to know why this situation happens and how to fix it. I don't want to check `netstat -ntlp` every time I restart my docker images.

## **Environment**:

OS: `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64)`

Docker:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:42:29 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:42:29 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Python: `Python 2.7.6`
Twisted: `17.1.0`

Comment: It happens because you did not handle an exception and you can't see the details of it because of your logging configuration.

Comment: Logging work `parallel` on an app, so logger is exception(or whatever) handler can't be add to your app directly. `kill or stop` required `from outside to inside` direction, you can't kill/stop any thread/process if include a external thread/process. Create `app loop` is easy, but `app life loop` required check every status + events.

Comment: @KlausD. I will look into the logging thing, it only throws this error messages after starting a problematic docker image.
@dsgdfg Do you mean the python process or twisted tcp connection is not killed by `docker kill` command? Then how to explain this happens just occasionally?

Answer (score 0):

First the obvious, have you tried the following,

```
docker restart <container name>
```

If it doesn't work as well try following, as a last resort.

```
docker kill --signal=SIGKILL <container name>
```

Comment: I will give a try. Since this situation happens occasionally, I might need some time to observe. Thanks a lot and hopefully this answer would help me. Probably I need to revise docker's docs a bit more as well.